Flexible or Expanded Couldn't Fix A RenderFlex overflowed by 2519 pixels on the right Error
My parent container widget uses the Expanded widget and my Text Widgets are not wrapping my texts. I am getting this error: Overflowing or RenderFlex error.
I tried wrapping the Text Widgets with Flexible or Expanded widgets but still, it didn't work.
Flexible(child: Text(postContent)),

Please post more of your code.

If it's a text widget and it's too long for the screen, you can try wrapping it in a 'SingleChildScrollView' and set the scrollDirection to Axis.horizontal. This will allow you to scroll through the text. If you want it to go onto another line, this solution wont work

Just make sure, your text is a multiline, not displayed on a single line using softWrap : true .
 Expanded(
    Text(
     postContent,
     softWrap : true,
     overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
     )
    )

Note: if that text is very long which exceeds the screen height so, it's preferable to be in a scrollable view. i mean your screen is scrollable. and of course that text should expand horizontally not vertically (that Expanded should be within a row).
